# php report button

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a search script and on each search result I want a report link button. I am not sure how to make one. I have looked on google for answers but cannot come up with anything. Can anyone give me an idea of what to do? or does anyone know where there is an example of this? I plan on using the link id and making a new table on mysql to send reports to. I am just looking for a basic button to send reports to mysql I am just not sure what would be the best way to do it. I have the data for the link id's I just need to be able to report it to a new table I am assuming. Any suggestions or examples are very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Making a *button* in HTML? Making this button *do* something specific?

Comment: no I am just trying to figure out what is the best way to go about making the script. Do I just run an insert to the db? is it as simple as that?

Comment: I figure I could use something like if string{ insert into db}else nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,

First you will want to create that new table in your database to capture this information.  Lets assume to you will have the following fields (very basic, you may want to add more): `ReportId`, `LinkId`, `DateReported`. `ReportId` is our primary key, `LinkId` is the ID you reference in your question and the `DateReported` is the server time we logged the transaction.

With this table created you are going to want to create a new php page, lets call it `report-link.php`.  You are going to want to make this page accept a querystring variable called `linkid` (accessible in the `$_GET[]` collection).  In the code of this page you will want to write a SQL query that inserts the value of the `linkid` parameter into the new link report table in the database (along with the `date()`).

On your search page you will be able to have users report an entry by clicking a link with the href of `/path/to/report-link.php?linkid=<?php echo $link_id; ?>`

Please note this example is very simplistic in nature, and offers no security for spamming, pleasant end user experience after they click the link, but this is the process you will want to follow in setting this feature up.  After you have it working you can spruce up the experience for your users.

Comment: Okay cool, that's all I needed. I just wanted some basic info. I can work with this. Thank you.